# Reset AD expired password with user credentials using a PowerShell script

Tags: active-directory, powershell

there!

I am new to Powershell and I need some help with this script.

I have just began to work helping our sysadmin with some tasks inside a Windows Server 2008 R2 AD Domain environment. I am trying to write a simple PowerShell script that allow the user to reset her own expired passwords, but it isn't working. This is the script:

```
$usuario = Read-Host "Introduzca el nombre de usuario";
$antigua = Read-Host "Introduzca la contraseña antigua" -AsSecureString;
$nueva = Read-Host "Introduzca la nueva contraseña" -AsSecureString;
Set-ADAccountPassword $usuario -Credential $usuario -OldPassword $antigua -NewPassword $nueva -Reset -Server <<ADServerName>>;
```

After execution, I get the following result:

> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: ({user}:ADAccount) [Set-ADAccountPassword], UnauthorizedAccessException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management 
>       .Commands.SetADAccountPassword

The user trying to reset her own password has no kind of admin permissions.

I don't know what is wrong with this, but I am sure that I am bypassing some PowerShell and/or AD fundamentals.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Enrique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is now working, with two little modifications:

- Adding "-Identity" before the first variable $usuario
- Setting the permission "Reset Password" of the "SELF" object in the "Security" section of the user properties.